# Remove text from a mixed JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, regex

I'm working on Node.js script and I have a mixed .wat file which contains text and JSON objects, I want to remove the text and keep JSON ojbects
Input file:

```
Some text 1
Some text 2
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
Some text 3
Some text 4
{"key1": "value3", "key2": "value4"}
```

This is how I'm expecting the Output file:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
{"key1": "value3", "key2": "value4"}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors/output is your current approach producing?

Comment: Loop through each line and see if you can parse it as json and if result is an object. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: It is if I don't have my coffee yet and feel generous

Comment: If that's the output of the "JSON" file. Then either it's been corrupted, or it isn't JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`file.split('\n').filter(line => line[0] == '{').map(line => JSON.parse(line))`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I think it is fairly self-explanatory and given that the question is on -1 now, I think we are good